# How to display array as a tree list by using id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some problem with rendering my array as a tree list. 
How can I rearange my array to render it as a tree list?
I have made it to render but up to the one level child only and one parent.
I need to render parents of parents and children of childrens if you understand me well.

To see my code clink here https://jsfiddle.net/Saban55/2j08utg9/3/

I have provide a fiddle code so you can see what I have made for now.
I need my list to be like this:

```
Node1
---Node2
---Node3
------con4
------con5
---Node4
------con6
---Node5
---Node6
---Node7
```

and so on to infinity.
How can I achieve that?
If you have any idea how can I solve this, or you have already making something like this
Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tree View` of material-ui. That will solve your issue and look good. You will just have to install and import it.

Here is the sample code. (Visit material-ui site for component api)

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TreeView from '@material-ui/lab/TreeView';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import TreeItem from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 216,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400,
  },
});

export default function FileSystemNavigator() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
    >
      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications">
        <TreeItem nodeId="2" label="Calendar" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="3" label="Chrome" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="4" label="Webstorm" />
      </TreeItem>
      <TreeItem nodeId="5" label="Documents">
        <TreeItem nodeId="6" label="Material-UI">
          <TreeItem nodeId="7" label="src">
            <TreeItem nodeId="8" label="index.js" />
            <TreeItem nodeId="9" label="tree-view.js" />
          </TreeItem>
        </TreeItem>
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes but I'm stuck with array. First I have to prepare array for map and use that material ui component. See this link https://jsfiddle.net/Saban55/2j08utg9/3/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Array, you need to use recursion to make it work to infinity. 
And it should maintain the data structure like this:

```
{
"_id": "node1",
"data": "Node 1",
"children": [
  {
    "_id": "node2",
    "data": "Node 2",
  },
  {
    "_id": "node3",
    "data": "Node 3",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": "con4",
        "data": "Con 4"
      },
      {
        "_id": "con5",
        "data": "Con 5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "node4",
    "data": "Node 4",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": "con6",
        "data": "Con 6"
      }
     ]
   },
 {
    "_id": "node5",
    "data": "Node 5",
  },
 {
    "_id": "node6",
    "data": "Node 6",
  },
 {
    "_id": "node7",
    "data": "Node 7",
  },
]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I achieve that?